# Identity, WIF, SAML and a 3rd party IdP

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, saml, windows-identity

We are trying to get an intranet site to work against a 3rd party external ID Provider (Okta) that is federated with our internal AD.

We've managed to use Ultimate SAML to parse the SAML token returned to the site but are looking at other options like WIF and ThinkTecture.IdentityModel.

I've been trying to find a sample that **actually works** against our 3rd party IdP using MVC 4 / .Net 4.  Documentation we have found for this stuff is either wrong of non-existent or extremely complex.

Can anyone suggest a really simple sample that actually works and is understandable my mere humans?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is SAML the only option available on Okta? Can't you enable WS-Federation? or OAuth?

There're prebuilt libraries for both on the .NET world (WIF and DotNetOpenAuth). That would be the simplest.

On the other hand, is this an internal app with users on AD only? The value of an ID Provider is to connect to external IdP (not necessarily your own).

If the users of the app are just on AD, use Windows integrated security. That is even simpler.

Comment: Yeah using Windows Auth would be nice but we want the apps to work on and off domain without a VPN.  Okta is good for this.  We also need to pass the tokens between sites and services so SAML sounded like the logical choice...